# Digest password authentication with JAX-WS in Spring for webservice client

Tags: java, web-services, security, spring, jax-ws

I have a Spring application that uses JAX-WS to consume another web service. Everything works fine but now this web service has been switched to require digest passwords. How could I accomplish this with JAX-WS?

I see from Sprig documentation that this should be possible but I cannot find any code samples with JAX-WS: http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html#d4e2684

Has anyone done this earlier? Any code samples would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can't. The example you give is WS-Security - which is NOT the same thing as what I believe you mean - which is raw http digest authentication at the server.

Comment: Digest authentication seems to be quite common these days. Is it really true than that JAX-WS cannot solve the situation and I have to switch to some other library?

Comment: You should look around, in that  diffrent JAX-WS implmenetations may have ways to solve it. But JAXWS by itself normally only supports BASIC auth at the http level.

Comment: I guess I have to switch to Axis2 then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around and reading documentation it seems that digest authentication is not possible currently with JAX-WS. The surprising part is that it shouldn't be too difficult to implement using existing tools. I didn't go this way but I'll write it down anyway in case if someone else would be interested to take the challange.

JAX-WS supports adding handlers that modify the message or its headers before it's sent over the wire. Obtaining nonce and calculating password digests could be done in that phase as well. There is a [blog post](http://pablocastilla.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/wssecurity-with-jax-ws-and-wss4j/) that adds handlers to encrypt and decrypt the messages that could be used as a base for this.

Axis2 that has digest authentication support uses [Apache WSS4J](http://ws.apache.org/wss4j) for security. So WSS4J project must have all the methods to calculate values, the only required part would be to call the right methods in the JAX-WS callback handler (and get the nonce).

Comment: Unfortunately, by the time these handlers are called, it appears to be way too late. To set the handlers, you have to already have an instance of BindingProvider. You get one of those from a Service. And to get a Service, you have to fetch the WSDL. If the WSDL asks for credentials (which it does in our case), blam, you're not getting an API handler.